# python file overwriting with os module

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, copy, shutil

I am writing a program that will move files from one folder to another. Sometimes I overwrite files in the process. Whenever I run the file however, I am asked "Overwrite C:... (Yes/No/All)". I want my program to always select "All" automatically. Thank you in advance

```
import os
from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()
sourceplayers = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\...\players' 
destinationplayers = 'C:\\memory\Will\players'
sourceuserdata = ('C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\...\remote'
destinationuserdata = 'C:\\\\memory\\Will\\remote'

def copyout(): 
    os.system ("""xcopy "%s" "%s" """ % (sourceplayers, destinationplayers)) 
    os.system ("""xcopy "%s" "%s" """ % (sourceuserdata, destinationuserdata)) #save


def movein():
    os.system ("""xcopy "%s" "%s" """ % (destinationplayers, sourceplayers))
    os.system ("""xcopy "%s" "%s" """ % (destinationuserdata, sourceuserdata))  

button = Button(screen, text="save", command=copyout)
button1 = Button(screen, text="overwrite", command=movein)
button.pack()
button1.pack()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use a flag.  you can try writing to stdin using [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) which should do exactly what you want:

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

p = Popen(["xcopy",sourceplayers, destinationplayers],stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("All\n")
p = Popen(["xcopy",sourceuserdata, destinationuserdata],stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("All\n")
```

Either way you should really be using the subprocess module over os.system, subprocess is a replacement for os.popen, os.system etc..

If `/y` would work for all files, use `subprocess.check_call`:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["xcopy","/y",sourceuserdata, destinationuserdata])
```

If you want the previous command to return before the next is run put a `p.wait()` in between each call to wait for the process to return.

If you are replacing a file then you don't need to look outside of python, you can use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```
from shutil import move
move(sourceplayers, destinationplayers)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I simply added the /y and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using system calls to do the moving. You could use a combination of [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list all the files and directories inside the source one, and [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to do the moving.

Comment: I attempted to use shutil previously, but it wouldn't let me copy from my program files (I apologize as I forgot to specify this in my question). A few users suggested that I add a /y and it worked. Thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [TechNet docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx), it looks like `xcopy` takes a `/y` flag that "Suppresses prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an existing destination file."

I imagine you would use it like this:

```
os.system ("""xcopy "%s" "%s" /y""" % (sourceplayers, destinationplayers))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing that link. It helped clear up a few of my questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `/y` switch as part of your xcopy command to always overwrite the files but if you strictly want to provide input (select All) as per your question, try something like https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect

Comment: Thank you for your response! I added the /y and it fixed it!